# Overlapping inline div

Tags: html, css, inline

I have [this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/2bLs7/3/) and I'm trying to solve it using jsfiddle but I'm not good in css. Hoping that you can help me solve this. I wanted to separate the next div on the second line. Just a little space to avoid the overlapping. I need it to display inline but the problem is if it goes to the next line, the next line of divs overlaps the previous line of divs. How can I add a margin from it knowing that I'm setting all the divs to display inline?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this acceptable?

http://jsfiddle.net/2bLs7/11/

```
.a{
    border:solid 1px black;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 1px;

    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline
}
```

Changing to `inline-block` might not be what you're after, but if you don't mind doing that, this seems good.

I included the hacks necessary to make this [*work in IE7*](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.a {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

See there, I use `inline-block` oppose to `inline`. `margin: 5px 0 0 0;` tells it to have `5px` of margin on top.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `line-height: 150%` to it to add a gap.