# How to give Internet Explorer different CSS lines?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, inline, compatibility

Imagine I'm having a `DIV`. I want to display it in a row with other divs, so I'm giving it `display: inline-block` along with other style definitions in a CSS sheet.

Now Internet Explorer wants to have `display: inline;` for the behavior I want.

How do I give Internet Explorer a seperate styling command to overwrite the definition for good browsers, so only IE will have `display: inline;`. Due to technical limitations I cannot use `<![If IE] -->`-stuff in HTML, I need to stay within the CSS file.

Comment: please specify the IE you are talking about. They don't behave all the same for inline-block elements

Comment: IE version 5 till 8. (They are all affected)

Comment: I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470358/how-to-give-internet-explorer-different-css-lines/5470395#answer-5470395) to reflect you comment

Comment: You need `zoom: 1` (or any other property that gives `hasLayout`) in most circumstances to make `inline-block` work in IE7 on block-level elements. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use selectors like so:

`\9` – IE8 and below, `*` – IE7 and below, `_` – IE6

So in your case:

```
*display: inline;
```

You can simply add this to the rest of the css:

```
div{
display: inline-block;
// some;
// other;
// css;
*display: inline;
}
```

[Read my blog post on this.](http://ajthomas.co.uk/blog/?p=299)

**Update**

> IE version 5 till 8. (They are all
>   affected) – [Cobra_Fast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522479/cobra-fast) 1 min ago

So in this case, you'd use

```
div{display\9:inline;}
```

Comment: There are a few ways to add 'IE Hacks' i found this method the least intrusive.

Comment: Just don't use invalid CSS. See @Peeter answer for conditional CSS.

Comment: cheers :) It goes without saying i know, but so many people dont accept the answer. This site is dependant on it.

Comment: @eisberg unfortunately some time "hacks" can not be avoided. Especially if you're editing legacy sites, that were developed prior to reset.css etc.

Answer (score 1):

A horrible way to do it is: http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks

Even though you cannot change the HTML I'd read up on http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Answer (score 0):

IE actually has quite good support for inline-block - if the element is originally an inline element. So try using a `span` instead of the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

To make `inline-block` work on block-level elements in IE7, I frequently add this to my answers:

- [Overlapping inline div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162957/overlapping-inline-div/5162975#5162975)
- [One list, simple float left, different cell sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431519/one-list-simple-float-left-different-cell-sizes/5432036#5432036)
- [How do I center a list as shown here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360538/how-do-i-center-a-list-as-shown-here/5366675#5366675)
- [multi-line tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083177/multi-line-tabs/5085163#5085163)
- [Remove margin between rows of overflowing inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358974/remove-margin-between-rows-of-overflowing-inline-elements/5359033#5359033)
- [How can I wrap content around a UL CSS Menu so content is seamless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032777/how-can-i-wrap-content-around-a-ul-css-menu-so-content-is-seamless/5033901#5033901)

I sure hope what I'm suggesting everywhere actually works :D

> See: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

```
selector {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```