# CSS: help neded for IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

For some reason http://funnyfurniture.net/ and http://funnyfurniture.net/p/5/teak-root-garden-chair/ are so badly broken in IE7. Can somebody suggest a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `display: inline-block` on `.content li.shadow-pod`.

IE7 only supports `display: inline-block` on elements that are naturally `inline` (such as `<span>`), unless you hack it into shape. Use this:

```
.content li.shadow-pod {
    /* your other rules */

    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

That's using the [Star Property Hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack) to tell only <IE7 to apply the `display: inline` rule.

It is invalid CSS, but it does no harm. It's fine to break validation *provided that* you understand what you're doing. That said, you could always use a valid hack or a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) instead:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
.content li.shadow-pod {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Also, see this previous answer I wrote: [How to give Internet Explorer different CSS lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470358/how-to-give-internet-explorer-different-css-lines/5470527#5470527)

Answer (score 0):

you're using

```
.content li.shadow-pod {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

inline-block isn't fully supported in ie7

try `float:left` instead