# Last row list items are missing bottom margin on IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm wondering why list items as last row are missing bottom margin on IE7?

http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/sW5DB/
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (annoying) ways to fix it still using floats, but the easiest solution in this case is to switch to `display: inline-block`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/3rjdf/

Replacing `float:left` with three new properties:

```
ul { width:300px; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; list-style:none; background:#ccc; }
li { display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1; /* float:left; */ width:98px; height:120px; margin-bottom:30px; border:1px solid black; background:#f0f0f0; }
```

[`*display:inline; zoom:1;` is explained here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470358/how-to-give-internet-explorer-different-css-lines/5470527#5470527) Suffice to say that it makes it work in IE7.

I also had to collapse whitespace in your HTML (why? read [*1*](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/) and [*2*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)):

```
<ul>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No problem. For what it's worth, this is what I came up with still using `float`s: http://jsfiddle.net/PUv4Z/ - I don't really like all the extra classes though, I decided I'd rather go for `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Sweet! I'll refer to your second answer when I need it.